# Codeigniter - How to validate a list of dynamic input fields where the validation rule depend on another dynamically created field

Tags: codeigniter, validation, dynamic

I am new to Codeigniter and I am using Codeigniter 2.1.3.

**Scenario:**

I have a 'Lesson' record,

a 'Lesson' can have **zero or multiple** 'Lesson_student' records,

each 'Lesson_student' record requires a payment_type, and a payment amount (all required fields),

depending on the payment_type for that student (in that 'Lesson_student' record), the amount has a different validation rule.

**For example,**

if the payment_type for that particular 'Lesson_student' record is 'Pre-pay', the amount has to be 0,

if the payment_type for that particular 'Lesson_student' record is 'Discount code', then amount has to be greater than 0. (could be anything)

In my form, i use jquery to create the 'Lesson student' fields dynamically, 
so each 'Lesson_student' record would have the following fields:

```
<input type="text" name="student_names[]" />
<input type="text" name="payment_types[]" />
<input type="text" name="payment_amounts[]" />
```

When i submit my form, they comes through as:

```
Array
(
    [student_names] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test name 1
            [1] => Test name 2
        )
    [payment_types]=> Array
        (
            [0] => Discount
            [1] => Pre-pay
        )

    [payment_amounts] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 0
        )
)
```

**here comes the question:**

**Question One:**

If i set the validation rules as followed:

```
array(
        'field'   => 'student_names[]',
        'label'   => 'Student name',
        'rules'   => 'trim|xss_clean'
),
array(
        'field'   => 'payment_types[]',
        'label'   => 'Payment type',
        'rules'   => 'trim|xss_clean'
),
array(
        'field'   => 'payment_amounts[]',
        'label'   => 'Payment amount',
        'rules'   => 'trim|xss_clean'
),
```

I allow my 'Lesson' record to have **0 or more** 'Lesson_student' record,

however, with this setting, i won't be able to detect 'Lesson_student' records without a student_name or payment_type.

E.g

```
Array
(
    [student_names] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => Test name 2
        )
    [payment_types]=> Array
        (
            [0] => Discount
            [1] => 
        )

    [payment_amounts] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 0
        )
)
```

But if i set the validation rules as followed:

```
array(
        'field'   => 'student_names[]',
        'label'   => 'Student name',
        'rules'   => 'trim|xss_clean|required'
),
array(
        'field'   => 'payment_types[]',
        'label'   => 'Payment type',
        'rules'   => 'trim|xss_clean|required'
),
array(
        'field'   => 'payment_amounts[]',
        'label'   => 'Payment amount',
        'rules'   => 'trim|xss_clean|required'
),
```

My 'Lesson' record now has to have at least one 'lesson_student' record, which again, isn't right.

***Question: Is there anyway i can achieve both at the same time?***

**Question two:**

Any of the above validation settings only allows me to check for the each field invidivdually with no relation to other fields for the same 'Lesson_student' record

is there any way for me to validate the value $_POST['payment_amounts'][1] against the value $_POST['payment_types'][1] in my validation rule setup?

Any help would be greatful.

Thanks

======================================================================

**[Edit]**
found a solution, using the technique mentioned in here: [codeigniter form validation for dynamic form input names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186618/codeigniter-form-validation-for-dynamic-form-input-names)

i looped through the $_POST data, and built a 'Lesson_student' array based on the $_POST data. 
so it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [student_name] => Test name 1
            [payment_type] => Discount
            [payment_amount] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [student_name] => Test name 2
            [payment_type] => 
            [payment_amount] => 0
        )
)
```

Then, in my model

```
foreach ($lesson_students as $index => $info) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('student_names[' . $index . ']', 'Student name', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('payment_types[' . $index . ']', 'Payment type', 'trim|required');

    $rule = 'trim|required|numeric';
    $rule .= ($info['payment_type'] == 'Discount') ? '|greater_than[0]' : '';
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('payment_amounts[' . $index . ']', 'Payment Amount', $rule);
}
```